# how to transpose different groups from column to row in R or excel

Tags: r, excel, transpose

I searched a few answers but it seems none can answer my question

I have a data look like this (2 columns, 2 groups group"1" and group"2")

- 1 10
- 1 20
- 1 50
- 2 40
- 2 30
- 2 60

and I want to transpose it from column to row by each group
the result will look like this

- 1   1  1
- 10 20 50
- 2   2  2
- 40 30 60

Since I have a lot of groups, I cannot manually do it one by one. Could anyone please help me? Thank you.

Thanks guys, since all groups have the same length (inspired by the comment from Floris), actually I can simply just use matrix to solve the problem

```
    x=read.table(header=F,text="10 20 50 40 30 60")
    matrix(x,nrow=2,byrow=T)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your first column is a label, and your second column is a value. Do you really need your labels to be transposed in a row above the values, or do you really need to have the values only. Also - are the groups all of the same length? I'm asking because there may be some clever tricks...

Comment: @Floris is right, you're not doing anything useful by repeating the group name over and over again in its own row.  Also it would help greatly if you would tell us what type of data you have. i.e. matrix, list, data.frame, data.table, and what type you want back.

Comment: Thanks guys, you are right, I only need to transpose the values

Comment: Hi Floris, all groups have the same length, and you're right I don't need the label to be transposed, do you mind sharing your tricks with me? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x <- read.table(header=F, text="1 10
1 20
1 50
2 40
2 30
2 60")

do.call(rbind, by(x, x$V1, FUN=t))
##     1  2  3
## V1  1  1  1
## V2 10 20 50
## V1  2  2  2
## V2 40 30 60
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to use VBA, it's pretty trivial to write a short sub() that will do this for you. I am hard coding the address - you can figure out how to move it around.  I am assuming your data is on the active sheet when you call this macro, and you want the copies to appear to the right of the original (which are in columns A and B, starting in row 2 - giving you space for a label above). Also I am going to assume that your groups are numbered 1, 2, 3... and that you don't need their values copying. Then the code looks like this (press F-11 to open the VBA editor, insert a module, and copy this)

```
Sub bigSwap()
dim R as Range, c as Range
dim grp
dim grpCount(1 To 100) ' assuming no more than 100 groups, or adjust this number
dim i

' just making sure it's properly initialized
for i=1 To 100
  grpCount(ii)=0
next i


Set R = Range("B2", [B2].End(xlDown)) ' this finds all the cells with values
' note - I am using [B2] as shorthand for Range("B2")

For each c in R.cells
  grp = c.offset(0, -1).value  ' find the corresponding group
  [D1].offset(grp, grpCount(grp)).value = c.value
  grpCount(grp) = grpCount(grp)+1  ' keep track of # in this row
next

End Sub
```

I was not able to test this, but I believe it's good. If you run into issues, just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Transpose cluster of cell from column to rows

Assuming that A2:A16 contains the data, try...

C2, copied across and down:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$16,ROWS(C$2:C2)*3-3+COLUMNS($C2:C2))
```

Adjust the references, accordingly.

Try for one row first then do the next and then merge